# How do i make a test case run always, even in Rerun scenario

Tags: selenium, testng

I wanted to run my login test cases before any other methods in my class. I have used this code .

```
@Test(description="Account Login",testName="login", priority=1, alwaysRun=true)
public void login(){}
```

It works fine . The problem arises, when i **rerun** the suite . because testng.failed.xml does not contain Login  method .

Note :-

1. I cannot make this method as **BeforeSuite** or **BeforeClass** method
2. I have used alwaysRun=true , but it doesnt work

Please help me to solve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

You should use dependencies. So other test must depends on "login" method.

For example:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "login" })
public void method1() {}
```

More info [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#rerunning)

Hope helps!

Comment: I have test cases in multiple files . We have segmented login functionality into three test cases . These test cases must run before any other test cases . So i have added <test name="login"> in testng.xml specially for this purpose . But while rerun , only the methods which have failed added into testng.failed.xml .

Comment: @sharan If you you expecify the dependOnMethod , the main methods are not included in the testng.failed.xml file?